# i3 screen goes blank after 5 min inactivity

Tags: fedora, screen-lock, i3

I am using i3 on Fedora 22, without a DM.

The way I run it is with:

```
exec i3
```

in my /etc/X11/xinitrc-common file, and:

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" -a $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]; then
       startx
fi
```

in ~/.bash_profile.

My screen goes blank after 5 minutes of inactivity, for example when I am watching a movie and don't input anything. I need to touch my mouse or keyboard to wake it back up.

Without a display manager I'm not sure where this behavior is coming from, so that I could turn it off.

Thanks in advance for the help.

*edit*

I discovered and turned off DPMS with no effect:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I was close with the DPMS thing - I also had to turn off xset screensaver. I put the following script in my xinitrc.d:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset dpms 0 0 0
xset -dpms
xset s off
setterm -balnk 0
```